# How to solve api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll error while installing xampp server

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed the XAMPP server and there is a problem occurring name `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll` that is missing from computer.
I have installed also `Visual Basic C++ distribution 64bit`, but it still showing same error message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to (re)install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, either via Windows Update or download and directly install the Visual C++ Redistributable:

Install all pending Windows Updates
Go to Start – Control Panel – Windows Update
Check for updates and install all pending updates, then restart the computer.
After the restart repeat the steps above again until no more updates are available.
Download the Visual C++ Redistributable 2015
For Windows 64-bit
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)
For Windows 32-bit
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit)
Run the vcredist_x64.exe (64-bit) or vcredist_x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall if already installed
Run the .exe again and select Install and restart the computer